# How to use Python regex to swap two substrings while leaving chars in-between in place

Tags: python, regex

I have `"partone/parttwo"` and I would like to use regex to change this string into `"parttwo/partone"`.

[Using Python to substitute or swap substrings in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807072/using-python-to-substitute-or-swap-substrings-in-a-file) seems similar however in this situation the only thing that is known is that the two substrings will be separated by a "/", and not specifically what those two substrings will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'/'.join("partone/parttwo".split('/')[::-1])
```

`.split('/')` splits the string into two substrings in a list `['partone','parttwo']`

the `[::-1]` reverses the list

and the `"/".join()` rejoins the list into a string using '/' to join them

If you really wanted to do the regex you could do

```
re.sub(r'(.*)/(.*)', r'\2/\1', string)
```