# How to replace whitespaces with underscore and underscore with whitespaces of a string?

Tags: python, regex

Here I replace *spaces* with *underscores*, but I wasn't able to replace the *underscores* with *spaces*.

```
import re

def repl(string):
    pattern = re.compile(' ')
    match = pattern.search(string)
    new_str = pattern.sub('_', string)
    print(new_str)

repl('But I want_to bring_out something_that we_are back to stay.')
```

Output : `But_I_want_to_bring_out_something_that_we_are_back_to_stay.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python to substitute or swap substrings in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807072/using-python-to-substitute-or-swap-substrings-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.translate` is the best choice here for single character swaps as mentioned in other answers.

If you need multicharacter string swapping, you can use dictionary via function call in replacement section of `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'But I want_to bring_out something_that we_are back to stay.'
>>> d = {' ' : '_', '_' : ' '}
>>> re.sub(r'[ _]', lambda m: d[m[0]], s)
'But_I_want to_bring out_something that_we are_back_to_stay.'
```

- here, the matched portion is used as a key to get corresponding value from a dictionary
- use `m.group()` if your Python version doesn't support `m[0]` syntax

Answer (score 5):

you can use `str.translate` to replace multiple (single character) elements at once:

with your example:

```
s = 'this is an __example__'
translate_table = str.maketrans({' ': '_', '_': ' '})
print(s.translate(translate_table))
```

output:

```
this_is_an_  example
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
mystr = 'But I want_to bring_out something_that we_are back to stay.'
mystr.replace(' ', '$').replace('_', ' ').replace('$', '_')

# 'But_I_want to_bring out_something that_we are_back_to_stay.'
```

I used `$` but make sure to use character that wouldn't appear in your input.

**EDIT**

Or you can use [maketrans](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/maketrans) with [translate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/translate):

```
trans = str.maketrans({' ': '_', '_': ' '})
mystr.translate(trans)

# 'But_I_want to_bring out_something that_we are_back_to_stay.'
```

Comment: You could use `$$$$$$$` instead of `$` to be sure of this

Comment: @Nathan Good call, that's why I added the `maketrans` variant.